# count number of file in a directory python

Tags: python-2.7

The following syntax was used to get the number of files in my directory , but can you please help me understand this syntax.( how does ".next()[2]" help in calculating the python.)
I am a newbie in python please help me with it.

```
len(os.walk(path).next()[2])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to understand this syntax, I suggest you decompose it as follows:

`os.walk(path)` will return a generator (basically an iterator)

```
<generator object walk at 0x7f5e5acbd4b0>
```

`os.walk` is supposed to browse all levels of directories, you're asking for `next()` to get the first level (and not the subdirectories)

```
os.walk(path).next()
```

This will return:

```
(
    [0] -> The path you passed
    [1] -> list of All the first level directories in your path
    [2] -> list of All the first level files
)
```

In order to get the files, you'll ask for the element of index `[2]` in your list

```
os.walk(path).next()[2]
```

And finally so you can count the number of these elements, you use `len` (stands for length)

Here you go:

```
len(os.walk(path).next()[2])
```

Comment: Thanks with the answer .. i got a python file which uses a library to perform a task , how would i transfer my python script to my friend who does not have this library . ( can i make it as a executable file if so how)

Comment: If it is an external library, he can install it like you did, otherwise you can send it to him too, or you can send him the compiled version too (.pyc). Also , it depends on what OS you are ( example: in Ubuntu 14.04: some modules and librairies could be found at; /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.) Hope I helped. PS. If you are working together on a common project, I suggest you use a remote git : https://git-scm.com/ https://github.com

Comment: I converted it into .exe file so i need not worry about the libraries using py2exe, any way thanks a lot YOBA

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of files in a directory you can use listdir() method.

```
import os
files = os.listdir()
print len(files)
```

Comment: In this case the directories will be counted as files too.

Comment: Same output for len(files)  and what I did.

Comment: Of course it will be the same output. But len(files) is shorter, more readable and faster than for-loop.

Comment: i knew the len (files) which is much easier i just wanted to know how the above syntax works, but any way thanks alex